# Excel - Value not recognized in Range

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel I'm trying to compute a value which depends on other range value. I have a very strange problem: the same formula with different value doesn't work for some case.

This formula works:
`ROUNDUP(AVERAGE(IF(RangeName1=1;RangeName2));2)*100&" %."`

This one doesn't:
`ROUNDUP(AVERAGE(IF(RangeName1=2;RangeName2));2)*100&" %."`

I check and my `RangeName1` does contain these values: `1` and `2` (order like this).

Does anybody has an idea why the second formula doesn't work?

Comment: Does the first formula correctly calculate as you expect?

Comment: yes. But it seems that the second formula doesn't find the value egals to 2.

Comment: OK, then that is a puzzle. Wanted to check the formula in the first instance does in fact do what you intended, as if it did not that may explain the second. But now eliminated. Are the "1"'s and "2" in Excel defined as numeric or characters.  Could that be the issue?

Comment: What do you mean by 'it doesn't work' ?

Comment: How it work's? As per Documentation IF(logical_expression, true_val, false_val) is the way to use IF?

Comment: Ok the problem was the following one : I haven't declared my formula as a matrix formula so it didn't check all the line. I select the formula and press maj+ctrl+enter as the same time and it did the computing

Answer (score 0):

When I try your formula's both work fine.
Can you tell us what you are trying to achieve?

If you want to display percentage in a cell you could also use cell formatting, this way your cell will only contain the actual number displayed in a certain way instead. see http://www.excel-easy.com/basics/format-cells.html for reference.